# React/Node File Upload Fails in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

Recently discovered an issue while trying to upload files in Safari. I get the same issue in Safari 10.0.3 on macOS 10.12.3 as I do in mobile Safari on iOS 10.3.1. This code works perfectly in both Google Chrome and IE, but hangs indefinitely in Safari.

Also worth noting: the FormData posts successfully in Safari when there isn't a file(s) attached.

Here is my JSX/HTML:

```
<Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={() => this.refs.selectFiles.click()}>
   Browse <input style={{ display: 'none' }} ref="selectFiles" type="file" onChange={this.handleAttachments} accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif,.apng,.tiff,.tif,.bmp,.pdf,.xcf" multiple />
</Button>
```

Here is my client-side networking code:

```
export function createAction(action, files) {
const data = new FormData();
for (var prop in action) {
  data.append(prop, action[prop]);
}
if (files) {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
  }
}

return fetch('api/actions', {
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  method: 'post',
  body: data
});
}
```

Here is how the files are handled on the server:

```
function insertActionAndComment(req, res) {
  if (req.files) {
  funcs = req.files.map(file => {
    return db.proc('dbo.InsertAttachment', request => {
      request.addParameter('ID', TYPES.NVarChar, id);
      request.addParameter('Name', TYPES.NVarChar, file.fieldname);
      request.addParameter('File', TYPES.VarBinary, file.buffer);
    });
  });
  }
  //Other processing code

  Promise.all(funcs)
    .then(() => {
  //Send notification email, etc

  res.status(201);
  res.end();
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

router.route('/')
.post(upload.any(), insertActionAndComment)
```

I've found that imgur has implemented this functionality perfectly in their mobile site on Safari.

Here is an example of the FormData for the image in a `POST` on their site:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryvnoeYeAi7QAdnoE1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryvnoeYeAi7QAdnoE1--
```

And here's an example of the FormData from my file 'POST':

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryobH1qsBmUuSGQHiX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Screen Shot 2017-04-11 at 4.16.54 
PM.png"; filename="Screen Shot 2017-04-11 at 4.16.54 PM.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryobH1qsBmUuSGQHiX--
```

Comment: What is `action` at `createAction` function?

Comment: @guest271314 `action` is some other FormData fields that I include in my POST.

Comment: Have not tried safari. What exactly occurs?

Comment: @guest271314 the request just spins and spins... has been for 20 mins now.

Comment: What do you mean by "spins"? Is issue server side?

Comment: Where is `id` within `.map()` defined?

Comment: @guest271314 `id` is a randomly generated guid, sorry I didn't include the code for that.

I don't think it's server side since the code works in Chrome and IE, and if it was server-side, I'd expect it to return an error instead of "spinning". By spinning, I mean the Safari dev console has had a spinning gif next to that request for 20 mins, as if it's still trying to process.

Comment: Have little experience with `reactjs`. Does same issue occur where `reactjs` is not used? Are `.fieldname` and `.buffer` properties generated at server?

Comment: When iterating `FileList` why do you set the key for `FormData` to `File.name`?

Comment: @guest271314 what should I set it to instead?

Comment: `"files" + i` or `"files[" + i + "]"`? That is, how does server know key of `FormData`? You could use `.entries()` to get the key to reference property, though do not view that at occurring at `javascript` at Question. Not sure where `.fieldname` and `.buffer` are generated, and what they reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I've discovered that Safari doesn't play nice with Windows authentication, and this was the cause of my issue.

If you are able, go to IIS manager and switch from Windows auth to basic auth and files should upload successfully.